# Protecting sheet. Selective editing permissions in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps, spreadsheet-protection

I have a table like this:
[image]

***SourceSheet** (sample data) is available: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jxDEj894Ir_BQx1uEHo1D3SBmC6_Rd0zo2locLN9KAE/edit?usp=drive_link)*

---

I need to protect all cells but certain ranges can be edited by everyone and some ranges can be edited by only users specified by emails.

```
  var rangesToEdit = [
    "D5:G11",
    "L5:O11",
    "D16:G22",
    "L16:O22",
    "D27:G33"
  ];
```

Above ranges can be edited by anyone.

---

```
 var ranges = ["H5:H11", "P5:P11", "H16:H22", "P16:P22", "H27:H33"];
```

Above ranges can be edited only by certain users by emails.

---

For now I protected the whole sheet, then gave permissions to anyone for editing **rangesToEdit** range.

But when I specify ranges that can be edited only by certain users it does not work.

I have the code:

```
function editSheet() {
  try {
  var sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jxDEj894Ir_BQx1uEHo1D3SBmC6_Rd0zo2locLN9KAE/edit?usp=drive_link";
  var sheetName = "February";
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    protections[i].remove();
  }


  var rangesToEdit = [
    "D5:G11",
    "L5:O11",
    "D16:G22",
    "L16:O22",
    "D27:G33"
  ];

  
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protected Range');
  var unprotectedRanges = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < rangesToEdit.length; i++) {
    unprotectedRanges.push(sheet.getRange(rangesToEdit[i]));
  }
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotectedRanges);



  var emailList = ["osstem.data@gmail.com"]; // Замените адресами электронной почты нужные адреса     
  var ranges = ["H5:H11", "P5:P11", "H16:H22", "P16:P22", "H27:H33"]; // Укажите нужные диапазоны
  
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(ranges[i]);
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Редактирование доступно только определенным пользователям.');
    
    protection.addEditor(emailList[0]);
  }
  
} catch (error) {Logger.log(error.toString());}
}
```

---

So all cells protected, **rangesToEdit** can be edited by anyone, but **ranges** for some reason can not be edited by specified emails. How to set users by emails who can edit ranges. Other protectir rules also must stay.

Comment: I tried to do the last piece in a copy of your sheet. Even for me, it's not allowing the added editor to edit the range. Not fully sure but this seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linked question**:
[Google Sheet different cell ranges protection and access levels (all, specific, email-based)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78082607/google-sheet-different-cell-ranges-protection-and-access-levels-all-specific)

---

Based on the answer of @**Tanaike**:

---

```
function myFunction() {
  // Please set variables for your situation.
  var sheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veORLw3OrcIAtv83n4Vn1E4bhj4gYqV9N2ebtRjztrA/edit?usp=drive_link'; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  var sheetName = 'February';

  var editableRanges = ["D5:G11","L5:O11","D16:G22","L16:O22","D27:G33"];
  var rangesToProtect = ["H5:H11", "P5:P11", "H16:H22", "P16:P22", "H27:H33"];

  var allowedUsers = ['email@gmail.com']; // Please set email address you want to permit to edit the cells "rangesToProtect".

  // Remove all protections.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  [...sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET), ...sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)].forEach(p => p.remove());

  // Protect a sheet and set unprotect ranges.
  var editableRangesObj = sheet.getRangeList(editableRanges).getRanges();
  var rangesToProtectObj = sheet.getRangeList(rangesToProtect).getRanges();
  var p1 = sheet.protect().setDescription('Защита всего листа');
  p1.removeEditors(p1.getEditors());
  p1.setUnprotectedRanges([...editableRangesObj, ...rangesToProtectObj]).setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + editableRanges.join(","));

  // Protect ranges with emails.
  rangesToProtectObj.forEach(r => {
    var p2 = r.protect().setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + r.getA1Notation());
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(allowedUsers);
  });
}
```

---

**Result:**

- `["D5:G11","L5:O11","D16:G22","L16:O22","D27:G33"]` can be edited by anyone.
- `["H5:H11", "P5:P11", "H16:H22", "P16:P22", "H27:H33"]` can be editied by specified users only
- All other cells protected.

Thanks to **@Tanaike**.