# Google Sheet different cell ranges protection and access levels (all, specific, email-based)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps, spreadsheet-protection

Have this **Google Sheet**:
[image]

***SourceSheet** (sample data) is available: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3nQZ1ZS0Y9zUv1ZfdjQlWIVHSqf-wF4neNDksCse6Y/edit?usp=drive_link)*

---

Trying to implement protection rules:

- The ranges **B2:B10** and **B13:B21** can be edited by **everyone**.
- Ranges **D2:D10** and **F2:F10** can only be edited **by users specified by email account**.
- All the other remaining cells are **protected** and **nobody** can edit them.

---

```
function setEditPermissions() {
  var sheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r3nQZ1ZS0Y9zUv1ZfdjQlWIVHSqf-wF4neNDksCse6Y/edit?usp=drive_link';
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';

  protectAllCells(sheetUrl, sheetName )
  setEditable(sheetUrl, sheetName)
  setEmailAccess(sheetUrl, sheetName) 
}


function protectAllCells(sheetUrl, sheetName ) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Защищаем все ячейки на листе
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Защита всего листа');

  // Устанавливаем права доступа на редактирование
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
}



function setEditable(sheetUrl, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var editableRanges = ['B2:B10', 'B13:B21'];

 editableRanges.forEach(function(rangeStr) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeStr);
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + rangeStr);
    protection.remove();
  });
}


function setEmailAccess(sheetUrl, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Диапазоны, которые нужно защитить
  var rangesToProtect = ['D2:D10', 'F2:F10'];

  // Пользователи, которым разрешено редактировать диапазоны
  var allowedUsers = ['email@gmail.com'];

  rangesToProtect.forEach(function(rangeStr) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeStr);
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + rangeStr);
    // Удаляем все предыдущие редакторы
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    // Запрещаем редактирование всем, кроме указанных пользователей
    protection.addEditors(allowedUsers);
    // Разрешаем только указанным пользователям редактировать
    //protection.setWarningOnly(true);
  });
}
```

---

First step (protecting  the sheet worked by function **protectAllCells**). The next 2 steps (functions: **setEditable, setEmailAccess**) did not worked. But logic seems to be correct.

---

Is it possible to implement it using **Google Apps Script** and **Google Sheets** by codes?

Comment: You're mixing sheet protection and range protection. They're different.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55446219 Try to do what you want with the user interface first to get a better picture.

Comment: To confirm, in the process of securing all remaining cells with the restriction "nobody can edit them", are you also restricting yourself to the ability to edit them?

Comment: I am as administrator (and script creator) have access to all cells for editing and so on.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly guess your actual situation, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it? If my guess was not correct and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to make all users edit the cells `['B2:B10', 'B13:B21']`.
- You want to make the specific users edit the cells ['D2:D10', 'F2:F10'].

To achieve this goal, I prepared the following flow. To test my script, please do the following flow.

1. Prepare a Google Spreadsheet.
2. Share the Spreadsheet with "user A" and "user B". I am the owner of Spreadsheet.
3. Prepare a sample script.

   - Please set variables for your situation.
4. Run a sample script.

   - `var editableRanges = ['B2:B10', 'B13:B21']` can be edited by "user A", "user B" and me.
   - `var rangesToProtect = ['D2:D10', 'F2:F10']` can be edited by "user A" and me.
   - Cells except for `var editableRanges = ['B2:B10', 'B13:B21']` and `var rangesToProtect = ['D2:D10', 'F2:F10']` can be edited by only me.

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set your variables.

In this script, the email address of "user A" is `var allowedUsers = ['###'];` .

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set variables for your situation.
  var sheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit'; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var editableRanges = ['B2:B10', 'B13:B21'];
  var rangesToProtect = ['D2:D10', 'F2:F10'];
  var allowedUsers = ['###']; // Please set email address you want to permit to edit the cells "rangesToProtect".


  // Remove all protections.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  [...sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET), ...sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)].forEach(p => p.remove());

  // Protect a sheet and set unprotect ranges.
  var editableRangesObj = sheet.getRangeList(editableRanges).getRanges();
  var rangesToProtectObj = sheet.getRangeList(rangesToProtect).getRanges();
  var p1 = sheet.protect().setDescription('Защита всего листа');
  p1.removeEditors(p1.getEditors());
  p1.setUnprotectedRanges([...editableRangesObj, ...rangesToProtectObj]).setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + editableRanges.join(","));

  // Protect ranges with emails.
  rangesToProtectObj.forEach(r => {
    var p2 = r.protect().setDescription('Защита диапазона ' + r.getA1Notation());
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(allowedUsers);
  });
}
```

- I thought that the important point might be as follows. When the sheet is protected, the ranges `['B2:B10', 'B13:B21']` and `['D2:D10', 'F2:F10']` are set as the unprotected ranges. After this, the ranges `['D2:D10', 'F2:F10']` is protected with the email.

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

- The cells `['B2:B10', 'B13:B21']` can be edited by "user A", "user B" and the owner of Spreadsheet.
- The cells `['D2:D10', 'F2:F10']` can be edited by "user A" and the owner of the Spreadsheet.
- Cells except for `['B2:B10', 'B13:B21']` and `['D2:D10', 'F2:F10']` can be edited by only the owner of the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you. That works correctly. ['B2:B10', 'B13:B21'] can edit anyone, ['D2:D10', 'F2:F10'] can be edited only be specified user, all other cells protected.